# Azure WebJob not included in web app during build when using Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publishing 1.0.10 on TFS build machine

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, web-publishing

I'm currently using the 'Add Azure WebJob' functionality as part of the Azure SDK in Visual Studio to add a WebJob into a Web App that gets deployed to Azure. I use a custom .proj file for my build, and when I build using msbuild on the command line, the package that gets generated correctly includes the webjob. However, when I use TFS to build the custom .proj file, **WITH EXACTLY THE SAME COMMAND** the webjob doesn't get included. For whatever reason, the publish targets for the webjob in the targets file provided by Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish nuget package simply don't get executed. Has anybody run across anything like this before ?